# Prove existence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $f$ be a continuous bounded function on the interval $(a, +\infty)$ such that $\lim_{x \to+\infty}f(x)$ does not exist. Prove that for any $t \in\mathbb R$ there is a sequence $x_{n} \to +\infty$ that $f(x_{n} + t) = f(x_{n})$ for all $n \in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x_n+t) \to f(x_n)$ in the end?

Comment: I have no idea yet. @Denis Düsseldorf No, it's right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Counterexample.** Let $a=1,\ f(x)=\sin x+\frac1x$ for $x\in(1,+\infty)$, and $t=2\pi.$

Comment: +1 Very nice. Here I was trying to prove it... Will award the bounty later.

Answer (score -1):

Is this pigeon hole principle?

Your function is continuous and bounded so $|f(x)|<M$ always.  Then $ |f(x+t)-f(x)|<2M$ and this difference had better cross 0 infinitely many times. Otherwise,  $f(x+t)> f(x)+ \epsilon$ always contradicting that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: $f(x+t)>f(x)$ is not a contradiction to boundedness. I'd like an argument why one can get a specific positive $\varepsilon$ for which $f(x+t)>f(x)+\varepsilon$ for $x$ beyond some point. Consider e.g. $f(x)=e^{-x}$ on $[0,\infty).$ [of course this one has a limit but your answer didn't refer to nonexistence of the limit]